# Ruby merge array conditionally

Tags: arrays, ruby, merge

I have a two-dimensional array in ruby and try to merge data as follows:

```
a = [["a","1"],["b","2"],["c","2"],["d","3"],["e","4"],["f","4"],["g","4"]]
```

I want to turn it into

```
 [["a"],["b c"],["d"],["e f g"]] //merge each letter together if they have the same "key"
```

Could anyone help me figure out what is the most efficient way to do it? Thanks.

Comment: Please try something before asking look at Enumerable#group_by and give it a shot

Comment: That is a very peculiar target format.

Comment: @tadman I wonder if the OP meant `[["a"], ["b", "c"], ["d"], ["e", "f", "g"]]`.

Comment: Will the "keys" always be in order, as in your example?

Comment: @JordanRunning are you thinking `chunk_while` as an option?

Comment: @sagarpandya82 Yep.

Comment: @sagarpandya82 Or `a.chunk(&:last)`. For some reason I always remember `chunk_while` but forget `chunk`.

Comment: "I wonder if the OP meant..." then the question isn't well asked and should be voted to be closed. The OP can then fix the problem and re-open it. https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/256328/vote-to-close-unclear-questions-immediately-after-commenting and https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260263/how-long-should-we-wait-for-a-poster-to-clarify-a-question-before-closing

Comment: What is your desired result if the array were `[["b","2"],["a","1"],["c","2"]]`, `[["b"],["a"],["c"]]` or `[["b","c"],["a"]]`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One way to do this is to use `group_by` to group elements by the second value in each array then use `map` to collect and format the relevant values:

```
a.group_by(&:last).map { |k,v| [v.map(&:first).join(' ')] }
#=> => [["a"], ["b c"], ["d"], ["e f g"]]
```

See `group_by` and `map` in the [Ruby documentation](http://www.ruby-doc.org) for more information.

Answer (score 1):

Using Hash can be one way to solve it.

```
initial_array = [["a","1"],["b","2"],["c","2"],["d","3"],["e","4"],["f","4"],["g","4"]]
constructed_hash = {}
initial_array.each do |item|
  constructed_hash[item[1]] = constructed_hash[item[1]].to_a << item[0]
end
final_array = constructed_hash.values
```

Comment: Things like `_array` and `_hash` clutter up this solution with pointless verbosity but this is a solution. Don't forget you can break out elements in an array: `each do |a, b|` avoids `item[0]` and `item[1]`.

Answer (score 1):

This should work well for you too although it does build an intermediary `Hash` it only needs a single iteration.

```
a.each_with_object(Hash.new {|h,k| h[k] =''}) do |(v, k),obj| 
  (obj[k] << " #{v}").strip! 
end.values
#=> ["a", "b c", "d", "e f g"]
```

Or using an `Array` (assuming the "keys" are numeric and positional like they are in the question otherwise revert to option 1)

```
a.each_with_object([]) do |(v,k), obj|
  ((obj[k.to_i - 1] ||= "") << " #{v}").strip!
end
#=> ["a", "b c", "d", "e f g"]
```